# Give user input to put a specific int or char in a certain position in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Im playing around with arrays to make sure I really understand the concept so im making a tic tak toe game with arrays, or would like to. my question is, am i able to put a specific character/string/integer in an array position by user input?

for example, {0,1,2}
i want to have the user put an x in position 1 in the array.

could you give me an example of how this would work or what I would use, thank you!

Comment: `array[indexwhichyouinput] = value;`

Comment: Yes - this is possible.  But yes or no questions aren't that useful, and that probably isn't what you meant to ask.  Can you clarify your question further?

Comment: Yes, arrays and lists are generally mutable in Java, now start playing around already! Possibly fill the array with `enum Mark { X, O }`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you first declare an array

`char[] cArr = new char[3];`

Notice that you can have only similar types of elements in an array. For example, you cannot have characters, integers, strings all together in a single array.

Once your array is declared, you can start filling it with elements.

> for example, {0,1,2} i want to have the user put an x in position 1 in
>   the array.

`cArr[1] = 'x';`

Note that you can only put elements at positions `0, 1, and 2` in `cArr` as the size of `cArr` is `3`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Hashtable :

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

// in your class
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

// insert all elements into hashtable
ht.put( "x", "value 1" );
ht.put( "y", "value 2" );

// get an element specified by it's key
String firstValue = (String) ht.get( "x" );
```

Comment: Hashtable is not used as an array. Also, it has very different purposes.

Comment: I am not mentioned that Hashtable is used as array.Just suggested based on question last line.@KnowNoTrend

Comment: But they are using an array. Not a hashtable.